# How to escape single quote in javascript which is in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi 
I am getting property form properties file using locale,the below is the code for that

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="/filename" var="mybundle" />
```

by using the below code i am accessing one property

```
<fmt:message key="ErrorMesg" bundle="${mybundle}" var="ErrorMsgInfo" />
```

Now i want to populate this error message in javascript by using the below code which is inside of javascript

```
var InfoErrorMsg = "<c:out value='${ErrorMsgInfo}'/>";
```

I am using `InfoErrorMsg` inside alert.
Expected behaviour :**Please select 'We have a radiobutton**
 i am getting as :**Please select `&#039We have a radiobutton**
by looking this it's not able to display/process single quote. To overcome this i tried the following ways
**First**

```
String result = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("ErrorMsgInfo");
result = result.replaceFirst("'","\\\\'");
pageContext.setAttribute("d2dFexExInfoErrorMsg1",result);
```

**Second**

```
var InfoErrorMsg = "<c:out value='${fn:escapeXml(ErrorMsgInfo}'/>";
```

**Third** inside javascript i replace `'` with `\'`

```
InfoErrorMsg = d2dFexExInfoErrorMsg1.replace(/'/g, "\'");
```

and the below one also

```
InfoErrorMsg = d2dFexExInfoErrorMsg1.replace(/'/g, "\\\\'");
```

Can anybody please help me to solve this one